# Using ng-class on 'md-list-item' click in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Im new to `angularjs`. I have six `md-list-item` in my html page. What I want to achieve is that when I click each of the `md-list-item` is that it will add a `class`. I just want to add an **active** link when I click each of the link. Here's what my idea is:

```
<md-list-item ng-class="{'setAsActive': ifThisOneIsClicked()}">
   <p>Link 1</p>
</md-list-item>

<md-list-item ng-class="{'setAsActive': ifThisOneIsClicked()}">
   <p>Link 2</p>
</md-list-item>

<md-list-item ng-class="{'setAsActive': ifThisOneIsClicked()}">
   <p>Link 3</p>
</md-list-item>
```

Is that possible? If it is, How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle it with a scope variable `selected`. it will keep which item is selected. And with the `ng-click`  directive change that value according to the item.

```
<md-list-item ng-class="{'setAsActive': selected=='1'}" ng-click="selected='1'">
   <p>Link 1</p>
</md-list-item>

<md-list-item ng-class="{'setAsActive': selected=='2'}" ng-click="selected='2'">
   <p>Link 2</p>
</md-list-item>

<md-list-item ng-class="{'setAsActive': selected=='3'}" ng-click="selected='3'">
   <p>Link 3</p>
</md-list-item>
```

Another Option: In case you want to keep a list of selected items.

```
<md-list-item ng-class="{'setAsActive': isSelected('1')}" ng-click="selectItem('1')">
   <p>Link 1</p>
</md-list-item>

<md-list-item ng-class="{'setAsActive': isSelected('2')}" ng-click="selectItem('2')">
   <p>Link 2</p>
</md-list-item>

<md-list-item ng-class="{'setAsActive': isSelected('3')}" ng-click="selectItem('3')">
   <p>Link 3</p>
</md-list-item>
```

In your controller:

Keep an array with the selected Items.

```
$scope.selectedItems = [];
$scope.isSelected= function(index){
     return $scope.selectedItems.indexOf(index)!=-1;
}

$scope.selectItem = function(index){
    //TODO: check if it was already added
    $scope.selectedItems.push(index)
}
```

Comment: With that, you will only have one element with the 'setAsActive' class at a time. Maybe he wants the class added to each element he clicks on.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me, that's exactly what I want. @Manuel Obregozo

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best idea is make something that can be easy reusable, like a directive.

js:

```
angular.module('tAngularApp').directive('ngActive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                element.addClass('setAsActive');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You can use it easy only injecting the `ng-active` directive where ever you want this behavior, like:

html:

```
<md-list-item ng-active>
   <p>Link 1</p>
</md-list-item>

<md-list-item ng-active>
   <p>Link 2</p>
</md-list-item>

<md-list-item ng-active>
   <p>Link 3</p>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! What a smart way! @Yoan

Answer (score 0):

I just want to extend Manuel's answer.
If you want to handle 'click toggle' (the class will be added the first time you click and removed the second time) you can do that by using an object and booleans:

```
$scope.selectedItems = {}
$scope.isSelected = function (index) {
    return $scope.selectedItems[index] === true
}

$scope.selectItem = function (index) {
    $scope.selectedItems[index] = !$scope.selectedItems[index]
}
```

(The HTML doesn't change)

Also, as you're new to Angular, it's a good time to learn some tips:

https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY